# Nginx no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: php, nginx

I'm making a Chrome plugin that calls a PHP script on my server, but I keep getting the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error.

I have added the header settings in my Nginx config, so I have no idea what else could be the problem.

```
location / {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET';

     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm also having the same problem. I'm stuck for a days trying to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersModule enabled?
2. https://gist.github.com/michiel/1064640 a CORS Script.
3. Dont forget to clear the cache!

Comment: How do I enable that module?

Comment: nginx -V will list all configured modules.

Comment: It's not in there, so do you have a tutorial about how to compile and install that module?